# Phonegap APK - jarsigner -verify throwing an error - invalid SHA-256 signature file digest for res/layout/notification_action.xml

Tags: android, phonegap-build, jarsigner

I have created the keystore using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore xx_yy_zz.keystore -alias xx_yy_zz_alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Uploaded to Phonegap and generated a APK file

The signed the APK using the below command

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore xx_yy_zz.keystore xx_yy_zz.78.apk xx_yy_zz_alias_name
```

But when I verify the APK it throws the below error

```
jarsigner -verify xx_yy_zz.78.apk
```

Error:

**jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA-256 signature file digest for res/layout/notification_action.xml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-digestalg SHA-256` to sign, if you wish to verify `SHA256`.

`SHA1` [had been broken](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3173616/the-sha1-hash-function-is-now-completely-unsafe.html) and should not be used anymore, at all.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response. Unfortunately it throws the below error
```jarsigner error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256 MessageDigest not available```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, have fixed that. Why you even use `jarsigner`? Better use `apksigner` for Android packages, which also would support v2 and v3 signatures.